# pip 2.7 error `sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")`

Tags: 16.04, pip, python-2.7

- I'm using docker image of Ubuntu 16.04 [ros:kinect](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker) container.
- My problem is that when I upgraded pip 2.7 (python version `Python 2.7.12`) via `sudo pip install pip --upgrade`, it started to show the following error whenever I hit `$ pip` in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can you please tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have local pip installed.

Remove it with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip
```

and retry.

You can reinstall the pip by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pip
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it's true that there were many versions, I deleted them all, until I can't see anything if I use the command `ls /usr/local/bin/ |grep pip` but still the problem unsolved!

Comment: I suppose that you need to reinstall python-pip package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pip` .

Answer (score 0):

python2.7 only support pip version < 21.0

The only solution that worked for me was:

- removing pip completely

  sudo apt remove python-pip

  sudo apt autoremove
- downloaded pip-20.3.4.taz.gz
- installed it using easy_install from python-setup-tools

  easy_install (LOCATION)/pip-20.3.4.taz.gz

I hope this works for you